# How to store in a variable and perform protractor functions in shadow dom javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, selenium, protractor

```
browser.executeScript("document.querySelector(\"tahitiapp\").shadowRoot.querySelector(\"tahitigroups\").shadowRoot.querySelector(\"vaadin-button[tabindex='0']\").click();")
  .then(function() {
    console.log('Export Download button is clicked');
    browser.sleep(5000);
  })
```

I want to do something like

var ele = document...............
ele.click();

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here.  `querySelector` doesn't create variables.  You can store its _results_ in a variable.  Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to do something like this..... ```var clickOnexportButton = browser.executeScript("document.querySelector(\"tahiti-app\").shadowRoot.querySelector(\"tahiti-groups\").shadowRoot.querySelector(\"vaadin-button[tabindex='0']\").click();")
clickOnexportButton.then(function () {
  console.log('Export Download button is clicked');
  browser.sleep(5000);
})
});
```

Comment: I dont want to use an a Page Object Model.........store variable in one place and use it whereever needed.

Comment: ```var clickOnDateTextBox = browser.executeScript("document.querySelector(\"tahiti-app\").shadowRoot.querySelector(\"vaadin-ext-date-picker\").shadowRoot.querySelector(\"vaadin-text-field[id='input']\").click();");
    clickOnDateTextBox.then(function () {
      console.log('Clicked to Date TextBox');
      browser.sleep(2000);
    })``` is it the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think not a variable, but a function you can call:

```
    const myFunc = function () {
        return browser.executeScript("your script here;")
            .then(function() {
                console.log('Export Download button is clicked');
                browser.sleep(5000);
            });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're asking but you can add properties to window:

```
browser.executeScript('window.foo = () => document.querySelector("tahitiapp").shadowRoot.querySelector("tahitigroups").shadowRoot.querySelector("vaadin-button[tabindex=0]")')
```

And they will be available later:

```
browser.executeScript('window.foo().click()')
```

Comment: I am getting the error : JavascriptError: javascript error: Cannot read property 'shadowRoot' of null

Comment: I'm just showing you how to add window properties, that shadowRoot stuff is not mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `by.js()` which evaluate a JavaScript expression like `browser.executeScript`

```
let vaadiBtn = element(by.js(function() {
  return document.querySelector("tahitiapp").
        shadowRoot.querySelector("tahitigroups").
        shadowRoot.querySelector("vaadin-button[tabindex='0']");             
}));

vaadiBtn.click()
```

Comment: I am getting this error : Property 'click' does not exist on type 'Promise<unknown>'.

Comment: Can you run `document.querySelector("tahitiapp").shadowRoot.querySelector("tahitigroups").shadowRoot.querySelector("vaadin-button[tabindex=0]")` in browser console to see it can find the desired element or not.

Comment: It finds the element @yong